# Display contents not working in android device

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I am developing an `ionic` app and to display my `navigation drawer` perfectly, I use `display="contents";`. When I run the app on browser using `ionic serve` command, everything looks great. But when I run the app on my mobile device, my `navigation drawer` opens in a very weird way at the bottom of the screen with a very little space for scrolling.
This is my `sidemenu.html`:

```
<ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
  <ion-menu #menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
      <ion-row class="ion-padding">
        <div>
          <img src="../assets/dummy.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
        </div>
        <div id="user-info">
          <span style="font-weight: bold;">Salman Khan<ion-icon style="float: right; cursor: pointer;"
              (click)="goToProfileSettings()" slot="end" name="settings"></ion-icon></span><br />
          <span>myemail@email.com</span>
        </div>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item-group>
          <ion-item-divider>
            <ion-label>Account Settings</ion-label>
          </ion-item-divider>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item (click)="showMyOrders()" [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-item-group>

        <ion-item-group>
          <ion-item-divider>
            <ion-label>Payments</ion-label>
          </ion-item-divider>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of sidebar_payment">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-item-group>

        <ion-item-group>
          <ion-item-divider>
            <ion-label>Benefits</ion-label>
          </ion-item-divider>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of sidebar_benefits">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-item-group>

        <ion-item-group>
          <ion-item-divider>
            <ion-label>Basics</ion-label>
          </ion-item-divider>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of sidebar_basics">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-item-group>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
</ion-split-pane>
```

and this is the `css` I am using:

```
#user-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 195px;
}
ion-split-pane {
  display: contents !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it supported on your device? [See CanIUse data](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen like I said it's working fine when I run the app on browser and switch to responsive mode but when I install the app on actual device, it won't work.